# Removing sidebar from single product page in FACTORY wp theme

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, sidebar

I want to disable the sidebar completely from WooCommerce single product page, and make the page full width.

I have read and tried each and every document available but to nothing is available.

**Steps**:

1. Copied the following code to functions.php

   ```
   function remove_sidebar_shop() {
       if ( is_product() ) {
           remove_action('woocommerce_sidebar','woocommerce_get_sidebar');
           echo("Test if");
       }

       else {
           echo("Test else");
       }
   }

   add_action('get_header','remove_sidebar_shop');
   ```

(the echo parts were for debugging)

2. Commented the line `do_action('woocommerce_sidebar');` in `archive-product.php` after copying it to `my-theme/woocommerce`.
3. Commented the line `do_action('woocommerce_sidebar');` in `single-product.php` after copying it to `my-theme/woocommerce`.
4. Commented the whole `sidebar.php` file.

But nothing seems to work.

Comment: Yes I have done that within my theme only as i mentioned my-theme/woocommerce directory which i used for overriding woocommerce templates

Comment: In backend WooCommerce > system status (at the end), you have normally the list of overrides templates located in your theme. Is that right? Have you check in your backend products pages if you don't have additional options meta box (check before in top bar > screen option tab to see if you are displaying all options)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of head scratching, found a solution myself,

In the overridden single-product.php, till now i was commenting the line

```
do_action('woocommerce_sidebar');
```

But instead, commenting this line

```
do_action('woocommerce_after_main_content');
```

did the trick.

Cheers....